# Why the reactive function is not working in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I have built a Shiny App which executes SQL on an action button with user inputs and the then uses the SQL results in a few "selectInput" options to display data. However, I had an error regarding the "reactive" structure when I launch the app.

Error message:

```
Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

filter, lag

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

Note: the specification for S3 class “AsIs” in package ‘jsonlite’ seems 
equivalent to one from package ‘DBI’: not turning on duplicate class 
definitions for this class.

Warning: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation not 
allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that 
can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
Stack trace (innermost first):

44: .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext
43: .dependents$register
42: data_sql.roi
41: unique
40: server [/srv/shiny-server/cls-Analyst-upload/server.R#104]
 1: runApp
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do 
something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

reactive function in server.r

```
    data_sql.roi <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {

    withProgress(message = 'SQL Querying', detail = 'Executing ... ', value = 0.99, {

              fetch(dbSendQuery(mydb_roi, 
                                  paste("select var1, 
                                                var2,
                                                var3,
                                                var4

                                         from data_table1
                                         where var1 = ",input$advertiser_id,"
                                         and var2 = ",input$attribution_window,"
                                         and var3 in (",input$study_type,")
                                         and date(var4) between ",input$dates[1]," and ",input$dates[2]"
                            ), n=-1)

          })
})  


data.roi <- data_sql.roi()
```

Does anyone know why this reactive function don't work?

Comment: As the message says, `data_sql.roi()` can only be called within a reactive environment, that includes `reactive`, `eventReactive`, `observe`, `observeEvent`, `local`, and all `renderXXX` functions

Comment: Hi @warmoverflow , thanks! Got it - make sense. The "data_sql.roi()"  is returning the SQL result. How can I load the result into a df so that I can use it like "df$var1"?

Comment: You need to inspect the result object. Most likely it is a list with one of the items being a table/dataframe.

Comment: @warmoverflow Yes. I tried. It seems not did the exactly what I was trying to do. I want to have the result data-frame available in local so that I can use it for analysis. Something like "data.roi <- data_sql.roi()$df".